# Adding next and previous links to an automatic slideshow

Tags: slideshow

I've incorporated the following automatic slideshow into a webpage that I'm developing...

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_auto

...but would like the ability to manually move to the next slide or go back as shown here...

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow

W3schools provide both types of slideshows (manual and automatic) but not one where the manual and automatic features are combined. I've tried incorporating the CSS and JS of one in to the other but can't get it to work - presumably because both JS scripts are calling on the same functions. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Add two links to HTML :

```
   <a id="prev" href="#" >Prev</a>  
   <a id="next" href="#" >Next</a>
```

JS:

```
$("#next").click(function(){
    $('#slideshow > div:first-child')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
});

$("#prev").click(function(){
    $('#slideshow > div:first-child')
    .fadeOut(1000)
     $('#slideshow > div:last-child')
    .prependTo('#slideshow') 
    .fadeOut();
    $('#slideshow > div:first-child').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: hi thanks but not sure how to attach it to the existing JS found on https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_auto.